# Processing sketch causing a java crashed thread

Tags: object, native, illegalstateexception

I'm developing an audio-visual performance using Processing - I am getting the following and have no understanding of what it means, what's causing it, and hence how I might go about fixing it. Any  insight would be gratefully received. I am quite a newbie btw so some of the technical discourse can be quite a struggle for me to get to grips with - aye, there's the rub ;-)

I'm totally lost here - very much out of my depth. The Mac OS Problem report has 214785 characters, limited to 30000 here! Not sure what to include.

The log(?) starts with

```
Process:               java [66470]
Path:                  /Applications/Processing.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk-17.0.2+8/Contents/Home/bin/java
Identifier:            net.java.openjdk.java
Version:               17.0.2 (8)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Processing [2756]
Responsible:           Processing [2756]
User ID:               295663019

Date/Time:             2023-03-21 21:27:12.575 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H2026)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     6.6 (19P6064)
Anonymous UUID:        003EB816-66B7-7C59-C135-F9739BC372C6

Sleep/Wake UUID:       B366F8E5-F1DC-4450-A0C4-8CF29A189D5A

Time Awake Since Boot: 330000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       13000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        35  Java: main-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000004aaaaaaa8
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x4aaaaaaa8:
    OpenGL GLSL            00000001421f3000-0000000142208000 [   84K] rw-/rwx SM=ZER  
--> 
    VM_ALLOCATE            0000000700000000-0000000708000000 [128.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

It goes on to list 73 threads and concludes that with:

```
Thread 35 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000070000d9a7000  rcx: 0x000070000d9a3628  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000001fb03  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000070000d9a3650  rsp: 0x000070000d9a3628
   r8: 0x00000000000130a8   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x000070000d9a7000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x000000000001fb03  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007fff7368432a  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x000000071a555000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Thread 35 says

```
Thread 35 Crashed:: Java: main-FPSAWTAnimator#00-Timer0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7368432a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff73740e60 pthread_kill + 430
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff7360b808 abort + 120
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000103cb4601 os::abort(bool, void*, void const*) + 49
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000103f196c8 VMError::report_and_die(int, char const*, char const*, __va_list_tag*, Thread*, unsigned char*, void*, void*, char const*, int, unsigned long) + 2968
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000103f18afc VMError::report_and_die(Thread*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, void*, void*, char const*, ...) + 156
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000103f19771 VMError::report_and_die(Thread*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, void*, void*) + 33
7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000103de0e0b JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 363
8   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff737355fd _sigtramp + 29
9   ???                             0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 0 + 12297829382473034410
10  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelICLGraphicsGLDriver  0x00007fff2fd97650 glrWriteTextureData + 5981
11  GLEngine                        0x00007fff442172f1 glTexSubImage2D_Exec + 1557
12  libGL.dylib                     0x00007fff435a32ae glTexSubImage2D + 55
13  libjogl_desktop.dylib           0x00000001298cc6d0 Java_jogamp_opengl_gl4_GL4bcImpl_dispatch_1glTexSubImage2D1__IIIIIIIILjava_lang_Object_2IZJ + 304
14  ???                             0x0000000113b1e233 0 + 4625392179
15  ???                             0x0000000113b858c0 0 + 4625815744
```

The log continues with a long list of "Binary Images:" I don't know if these might be relevent or not - excluded here, and ends with

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=704.1M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=704.1M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=907.3M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=907.3M(100%)

```
                            VIRTUAL   REGION
```

REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced)
===========                     =======  =======
Accelerate framework               256K        2
Activity Tracing                   256K        1
CG backing stores                 1440K        4
CG image                          4124K        5
CoreAnimation                       56K       10
CoreGraphics                         8K        1
CoreImage                           32K        4
CoreUI image data                  312K        5
Dispatch continuations            16.0M        1
Foundation                           4K        1
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1
MALLOC                           269.7M      250
MALLOC guard page                   32K        7
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)           6528K        3         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
OpenGL GLSL                        384K        5
STACK GUARD                        860K       74
Stack                             63.8M       74
Stack Guard                       56.2M       46
VM_ALLOCATE                        5.4G      751
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)            36.2M        6         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                            40.8M      562
__DATA_CONST                       152K        4
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1
__GLSLBUILTINS                    5176K        1
__LINKEDIT                       414.5M      244
__OBJC_RO                         32.3M        1
__OBJC_RW                         1908K        2
__TEXT                           289.7M      532
__UNICODE                          564K        1
mapped file                      190.4M       24
shared memory                      644K       16
===========                     =======  =======
TOTAL                              6.8G     2639
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     6.8G     2639

Model: MacBookPro16,2, BootROM 1731.140.2.0.0 (iBridge: 19.16.16064.0.0,0), 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i5, 2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisPlusGraphicsItem, Intel Iris Plus Graphics, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR4X, 3733 MHz, Samsung, -
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR4X, 3733 MHz, Samsung, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x7BF), wl0: Oct 28 2020 14:13:29 version 9.30.357.42.32.5.48 FWID 01-767f6cce
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.6f8, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: K-Mix
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB-C VGA Multiport Adapter
USB Device: Apple T2 Bus
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Touch Bar Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 86.0
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 86.0

I am so so so totally without a clue here - any help would be so welcomed. Thx..

Comment: Welcome! Please, send us a larger extract your logs, with the root cause of your exception. The more description you can give about what you were attempting will also be useful.

Comment: Dear Marc, Thanks for your comment. Sorry for the delay I've been away with family. See above for larger log report. thx